# javascript - export multiple html tables into multiple excel worksheet

Tags: javascript, php, excel, worksheet

I have a page contain some table based on previous input process. Then I add download excel-file button so, the visitor can get the excel formatted file. But, the need is every table than appear in result page is will be generated in separate worksheet.

What I've try is

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) {
        return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    }
    , format = function(s, c) {
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
            return c[p];
        });
    };
    return function() {
        table = '.tabel_hasil';
        name = 'table';
        filename = 'aaa.xls';
        tables = [];
        if (!table.nodeType) {
            for (i = 2; i <= ($('.tabel_hasil').length + 1); i++) {
                tables.push($(".tabel_hasil:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").html());
            }
        }

        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: tables};

        document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
        document.getElementById("dlink").click();

    };
})();
```

The result is the tables is always appear in single worksheet.
Is there any solution or modification or else about this?